# Azure Offline Sync Performing a SUM operation

Tags: azure, mobile, service, synchronization, offline

I need to perform a SUM on the underlying SQLite store in Azure Mobile Services. This seems to be pretty complicated so far.. see the below thread, any takers?

I have a requirement in my app to SUM all the values of a column inside a table and return the result to UI. I can do this writing SQL against SQLite but within Azure App Services using a sync table I can only see ReadAsync which accepts OData syntax and no ability to SUM. Is there a way I can run bespoke queries against the underlying SQLite store? In a nutshell can I do 'SELECT SUM(col) FROM table'?

Depending on which language you are using, it's fairly easy to do it within code. JS has the map() method and .NET has LINQ, for example.

Thank you for your reply. I'm using LINQ and .NET in Xamarin Forms. I don't want to retrieve all the rows, could you provide a concise example in which I can do this? 'SELECT SUM(col) FROM table'? in the context of Azure App Services?

var sum = table.Sum(t => t.Field);

I have tried this way initially, but there is no method Sum on a Table of SyncTable in Mobile Services (Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client). I'm using System.Linq too. My environment is Xamarin Studio (using Xamarin Forms).

Apologies: table.ToListAsync().Sum(t => t.Field). This is an appropriate question for Stack Overflow, where you will get a wider community assistance as well.

Hi Adrian, thanks for your time, but ToListAsync will bring back all of the records and then a sum is executed. The SQL generated is 'SELECT * FROM Table' (I checked this). A sum is then performed on the full list. This is exactly what I'm trying not to do as I have thousands of records. I simply want to execute a 'SELECT SUM(*) FROM Table' on the underlying store without pulling back all the records. Can this be done?

Comment: Better to refine your question this way: "Is the any support for aggregate functions like Count, Sum, and Avg without returning all the records?" instead of pasting the discussion with Adrian ☺.